# SQLAlchemy OR_ Loop Generation Issue: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a piece of code that is generating multiple `OR` statements in a `WHERE` clause but it's returning the below error.

Any help appreciated.

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got <generator object TargetParentMixin.matches_target.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7f1910842e40>.
```

Method:

```
def match(
    cls,
    targets: Collection[TargetRange[IPAddress]],
) -> Select:
    return select(cls).where(cls.id.in_(select(cls.id).where(
        or_(*(
            cls.__class._inst_classes[tr.ver].start <= tr.start,
            cls.__class._inst_classes[tr.ver].end >= tr.end,
        ))
        for tr in targets
    ).distinct()))
```

Expected outcome example:

```
SELECT device_engine.id, device_engine.device_id, device_engine.name 
FROM device_engine JOIN device ON device.id = device_engine.device_id 
WHERE device_engine.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT device_engine_target.device_engine_id FROM device_engine_target WHERE 
    (device_engine_target.start <= 0x0A76FFFA AND device_engine_target.end >= 0x0A76FFFA) OR
    (device_engine_target.start >= 0x0A76FFFA AND device_engine_target.end >= 0x0A76FFFA)
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to have `.where(*(or_(...) for tr in targets)` i.e. you need to unpack the generator expression?